# Configuring Mongodb on Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoid

I am a total newbie to node, mongo, programming.

How do I configure my add-on mongolab database to my node app in heroku?  Use mongoid? Where do I install mongoid.

Sorry for the seemingly idiotic questions, I am a dad of a type 1 diabetic who is not a programmer but trying to get a database up that will transform her care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it through this [webpage](https://addons.heroku.com/marketplace/mongolab) and then follow this [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab).